# Why does Log Shipping .TRN file copy just stop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I apologize in advance for a long post, but I have had it up to here with the situation of having to delete Log Shipping (LS) configuration and starting it over for any DB that has got this error.

I have LS setup on 3 win2k8r2 servers (primary, secondary, monitor) with 100 databases backed up and shipped transactions from the **primary** to **secondary** and monitored by **monitor**. Backups and copies are run every 15 mins and then the ones older than 24 hrs are deleted.

Some DBs are very active and some not so active but shipped regardless for uniformity sake (basically to make secondary server identical to primary). Some DBs are for SharePoint 2010 and the majority are for inhouse apps.

The issue is that after all LS configs are set up, everything works well for about 3 to 4 days. Then I go to the Transaction LS Status report on the secondary, I see that randomly some LS jobs have an Alert Status, because the time since last copy is over 45 mins so no restore has occurred. This seems random and the only errors I see is from a SharePoint 2010 DB (WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_ReportingDB_77a60938_##########) which I belive is a Reporting DB that gets created weekly and LS just cannot figure out which the last copy to backup or to restore is.

I posted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42173/directory-lookup-failed-during-log-shipping) regarding that and I have yet to find a permanent solution.

For my main error (time since last copy) I have not seen anything that could have caused that and I don't get any messages (even though some alert statuses have been ignored for 3 days).

Anyway, I would really appreciate any input on understanding what's causing this issue and how I could fix it.

Comment: Are the target databases in use at all (standby)?

Comment: `I belive is a reports db that gets created weekly and LS cannot just figure which the last copy to backup or to restore is` when a database is recreated, you have to re-setup logshipping from scratch. What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @Kin the error regarding my previous post with the SP reports db is this _Cannot open backup device '\\SQLSecondary\LS-BackUP\WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_ReportingDB_77a60938-##########.trn'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).  RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally._
But for this post, _Could not find a log backup file that could be applied to secondary database 'InHouseDB'._ when I run 'SELECT *
  FROM [msdb].[dbo].[log_shipping_monitor_history_detail]' on the monitor server

Comment: @JonSeigel Nope, they're all for warm DR and are Standby/Read-Only

Comment: @shilezi It simply means that the file is not there. Are you sure that you are deleting the log backups after 24 hrs on the secondary server ?

Comment: @Kin On the Primary server using the LS GUI, I chose to "Delete files older than: 24hrs" and the Backup job schedule to occur every day every 15 minute(s) between 12:00:00 AM and 11:59:00 PM. And on the Secondary server, files are copied using the same/default schedule and i chose the "Delete copied files after:24hrs".
Once initialized, i watch the backup, copy and restore happen hassle free and 3 days later, 4 or 5 of 100 dbs won't copy.

Comment: @shilezi there is definately some process deleting those files or as in my first comment, you have to resetup logshipping as the report db gets created weekly.

Comment: @Kin I have been reconfiguring LS for those dbs whenever the copy time gets that high. I was just trying to figure why it stopped copying or whats causing it to stop. Feels like if i didnt do anything, it would be just a matter of time before it gradually stopped copied for all 100 dbs because as soon i reconfigure, the next day or 3 days later, another 2 or 3 db stops being copied as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9598/discussion-between-shilezi-and-kin)

Comment: I believe your delete job is causing the trouble. The error just says that it cant find the file.

Comment: @AnupWarrier im still having the issue. I reset the LS config back to default values where it deletes files older than 72hrs and I still get the copy failed/stopped/delayed error.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting both the source and destination servers housing the sql engines seemed to fix the issue. its been a week and all backup, copy and restore has no issues except for just that one SharePoint reporting db `WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_ReportingDB_77a60938-####-####-####-##########`.
Thanks to everyone for their input, as I at least came out of this more knowledgeable.